How do I keep sticky buttons aligned to left and right inside a Scrollable Div?
I have a product page that is horizontally scrollable, I trying to keep the buttons to the right and left to scroll, however, I am not able to set the Top position to those. Here is the code
<div style="height: 400px; background-color: darkgoldenrod"></div>
<div class="container" #widgetsContent>
  <button class="button-left" (click)="scrollLeft()">Left Button</button>
  <div class="scrollable-content">
    @for(p of products; track p){
    <div class="item" appDraggable>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img
          class="image"
          src="https://img1.forestessentialsindia.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/0ee050c3ffc3555709b9bb6062f4d7e9/2/1/21324-kesanta-advanced-hair-growth-serum-50ml-front_1.png"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="content-container">
        <div class="name">{{ p.name }}</div>
        <div class="review">
          <app-star-rating [rating]="p.rating"></app-star-rating>
        </div>
        <div class="review-count">{{ p.reviewCount }} Reviews</div>
        <div class="price">{{ p.price }}</div>
        <mat-toolbar style="background-color: transparent; padding: 0px">
          <button mat-flat-button>ADD TO CART</button>
          <span class="spacer"></span>
          <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-toolbar>
      </div>
    </div>
    }
  </div>
  <button class="button-right" (click)="scrollRight()">Right Button</button>
</div>

my CSS
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px; /* Adjust padding as needed */
}


.button-left {
position: sticky;
top: 20px; /* Adjust top position as needed /
left: 5px; / Adjust left position as needed /
z-index: 999; / Ensure buttons are above content /
background-color: #f0f0f0; / Example background color /
padding: 5px 10px; / Adjust padding as needed */
}
.button-right {
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px; /* Adjust top position as needed */
  right: 10px; /* Adjust right position as needed */
  z-index: 999; /* Ensure buttons are above content */
  background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Example background color */
  padding: 5px 10px; /* Adjust padding as needed */
}

.scrollable-content {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block; /* Display items in a row */
  width: 275px; /* Fixed width of each item */
  height: 415px; /* Fixed height of each item */
  margin-right: 10px; /* Margin between items */
  background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244); /* Example background color */
  border: 1px solid rgb(226, 226, 226); /* Example border */
  margin-right: 12px;
  position: relative;
}

Also, the highlighted space to be removed. Please help

I'm not certain what your problem actually is, but have you tried just using bottom instead of top, considering what you want seems to be your buttons aligned relative to the bottom of the viewport?

oh, wow.. i didn't even check that.. not sure how does it work.. i tried and now i can align the  buttons where i wanted. Can you please help me in the last comment

Can you clarify what you mean by "the last comment"?

i fixed it.. please ignore.. thank you Alex

You are taking an old approach to this issue. Consider instead using flexboxing, which is very versatile and works like a charm :


.body {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.sidenav {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  
  padding: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  background-color: #abfdec;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background: #ecdbfa;
  overflow: auto;
}

.filler {
  width: 20000px;
}
<div class="body">
  <div class="sidenav">
    <button>Some button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="filler"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidenav">
    <button>Some button</button>
  </div>
</div>




what about the right button. I want to use these buttons like Carousel (scrolling the content of the Container)

@SamK I have updated my answer, the only thing you need to change is the "content" div to put your carousel in
